# java.io.IOException: Error running exec() Working Directory: null Environment: null

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, ioexception

I am using [WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java) in application.

here is my code

```
loadFFmpeg();
String cmd="ffmpeg -i /storage/emulated/0/media/audio/a.mp3 -i  /storage/emulated/0/recording.3gp -filter_complex \"[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[aout]\" -map \"[aout]\" " + outputFile;
executeFFmpeg(cmd.split(" "));
```

and

```
private void loadFFmpeg() {
    FFmpeg ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext());
    try {
        ffmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {}

            @Override
            public void onFailure() {}

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {}

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {}
        });
    } catch (FFmpegNotSupportedException e) {
        // Handle if FFmpeg is not supported by device
    }
}

private void executeFFmpeg(String[] cmd)
{
    /*String workFolder = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir() + "/ffmpeg";
    String environment = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("Working Directory", workFolder);
    map.put("Environment",environment);*/
    FFmpeg ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext());
    try {
        // to execute "ffmpeg -version" command you just need to pass "-version"
        ffmpeg.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {}

            @Override
            public void onProgress(String message) {}

            @Override
            public void onFailure(String message) {}

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String message) {}

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                stop.setEnabled(false);
                play.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
        // Handle if FFmpeg is already running
    }
}
```

but I am getting following error

> 6784-6962/com.flipartstudio.playandrecord E/FFmpeg: Exception while trying to run: [Ljava.lang.String;@41803270
>                                                                          java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [/data/data/com.flipartstudio.playandrecord/files/ffmpeg, /system/bin/ls, -l, /data/data/com.example.foo/files/ffmpeg] Working Directory: null Environment: null
>                                                                              at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:211)
>                                                                              at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:168)
>                                                                              at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:123)
>                                                                              at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.ShellCommand.run(ShellCommand.java:10)
>                                                                              at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.doInBackground(FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.java:38)
>                                                                              at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.doInBackground(FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.java:10)
>                                                                              at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
>                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
>                                                                              at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
>                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
>                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>                                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
>                                                                           Caused by: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
>                                                                              at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(Native Method)
>                                                                              at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:209)
>                                                                              at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:168) 
>                                                                              at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:123) 
>                                                                              at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.ShellCommand.run(ShellCommand.java:10) 
>                                                                              at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.doInBackground(FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.java:38) 
>                                                                              at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.doInBackground(FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.java:10) 
>                                                                              at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287) 
>                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234) 
>                                                                              at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230) 
>                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080) 
>                                                                              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573) 
>                                                                              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

I have also added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your problem is that you declear `FFmpeg` once in **loadFFmpeg()** method and once in **executeFFmpeg()** . so in **executeFFmpeg()** your `FFmpeg` isn't loaded.

## Solution :

your code should be like this :

```
public class Main extends Activity{

FFmpeg ffmpeg;
Context context;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context = this;

    loadFFmpeg();
    String cmd="ffmpeg -i /storage/emulated/0/media/audio/a.mp3 -i  /storage    /emulated/0/recording.3gp -filter_complex \"[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[aout]\" -map \"[aout]\" " + outputFile;
    executeFFmpeg(cmd.split(" "));

}

private void loadFFmpeg() {
    ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(context);
    try {
        ffmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {}

            @Override
            public void onFailure() {}

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {}

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {}
        });
    } catch (FFmpegNotSupportedException e) {
        // Handle if FFmpeg is not supported by device
    }
}

private void executeFFmpeg(String[] cmd)
{
    try {
        ffmpeg.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {}

            @Override
            public void onProgress(String message) {}

            @Override
            public void onFailure(String message) {}

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String message) {}

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                stop.setEnabled(false);
                play.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
        // Handle if FFmpeg is already running
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Try this:

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

FFmpeg ffmpeg;
Context context;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    context = this;

    loadFFmpeg();
    String cmd="-i /storage/emulated/0/media/audio/a.mp3 -i  /storage    /emulated/0/recording.3gp -filter_complex \"[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[aout]\" -map \"[aout]\" " + outputFile;
    executeFFmpeg(cmd.split(" "));

}

private void loadFFmpeg() {
    ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(context);
    try {
        ffmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {}

            @Override
            public void onFailure() {}

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {}

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {}
        });
    } catch (FFmpegNotSupportedException e) {
        // Handle if FFmpeg is not supported by device
    }
}

private void executeFFmpeg(String[] cmd)
{
    try {
        ffmpeg.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {}

            @Override
            public void onProgress(String message) {}

            @Override
            public void onFailure(String message) {}

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String message) {}

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                stop.setEnabled(false);
                play.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
    } catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
        // Handle if FFmpeg is already running
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Reason**: 
`ffmpeg.loadBinary` is **Async**. It returns immediately but the task doesn't complete at that time.

**Solution**: 
You should put your code in `onSuccess()` of `ffmpeg.loadBinary` like this:

```
ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(context);
    try {
        ffmpeg.loadBinary(new LoadBinaryResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {}

            @Override
            public void onFailure() {}

            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                String cmd="ffmpeg -i /storage/emulated/0/media/audio/a.mp3 -i  /storage/emulated/0/recording.3gp -filter_complex \"[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[aout]\" -map \"[aout]\" " + outputFile;
                executeFFmpeg(cmd.split(" "));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {}
        });
    } catch (FFmpegNotSupportedException e) {
        // Handle if FFmpeg is not supported by device
    }
```